# For loop without using for statement

Tags: javascript, loops, decrement

I'm trying to write a program where you print a decrement by 1 loop, so if the value is 3 the output should be 3,2,1. But the output I get from this code is 3,2,1,0. Are there any ways I can fix this?

```
function loop(value) {
    while(greaterThanZero(value) == true) {
            printValue(value);
            value = reduceOne(value);
            console.log(value);
            value--;
    }
}

var value = 3;
var greaterThanZero = function (n) {
   return n > 0;
}
var reduceOne = function (n) {
   return n - 1;
}
var printValue = function (n) {
   console.log(n)
}
```

Comment: `(greaterThanZero(value) == true)` is not necessary `greaterThanZero(value)` already returns a boolean

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the same thing twice in each iteration (logging and decrementing). Remove the two duplicate statements so you can break out immediately instead of going two at a time.

```js
function loop(value) {
    while(greaterThanZero(value) == true) {
            console.log(value);
            value--;
    }
}
var greaterThanZero = function (n) {
   return n > 0;
}

loop(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function seems to be working as expected but you are seeing `0` because of this `console.log(value)`. It is just logging the value after decrementing it

```js
var value = 3;
var greaterThanZero = function(n) {
  return n > 0;
}
var reduceOne = function(n) {
  return n - 1;
}
var printValue = function(n) {
  console.log(n)
}


function loop(value) {
  while (greaterThanZero(value) == true) {
    printValue(value);
    value = reduceOne(value);
    //console.log(value);
    //value--;
  }
}


loop(value)
```